# How to pass Stringified JSON to C# Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, maps

I've spent the last night trying to figure this out.

Basically in Google Maps, I am able to generate directions, or waypoints, between two points that the user chooses in client side Javascript.

I ideally want to be able to store these in my database ( Im using C#.NET and SQL Server DB ) by passing these to a server side C# method..

I've got to the point where I can put the directions I need into a string by using:

```
*var string = JSON.stringify(response);*
```

Now, here's where I'm stuck.

How do I pass this to a C# webforms method?

I've seen an MVC C# solution to my problem as:

```
var str = JSON.stringify(data)

var city = {};
        city.Directions = str;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'usertrip.aspx/GetDirections',
            data: str ,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r.d.Directions);;
                }
        });
```

But I've tested, and have concluded that this won't work for webforms. Does anyone know how I can alter this code so that I can pass the string to a Webforms method and not MVC?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the GetDirections() code

Comment: This kind of thing _does_ work for ASP.NET web forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely do this kind of thing with webforms. The important thing is that you need to set up a webservice that exposes methods that can be hit by the ajax call. This awesome article called [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20161229045603/http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) proved invaluable for me to figure out how to accomplish what you're trying to do.

For an example (from the article) doing something like this:

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string DoSomething(string myJsonData)
  {
    // deserialize your JSON
    // do something cool with it
  }
}
```

Would allow you to hit the webmethod with your AJAX call. I can assure you that I've done this in many different asp.net solutions what don't use MVC so with a little bit of tinkering you should be able to get the information you need to your code behind.

Comment: Hi Jesse, I have tried the code from the same article, everything works except the c# code cannot pick up webform data, the NameValue[] formVars is empty. Do you have any suggestion on this. My post is here . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311890/error-with-using-jquery-to-post-form-data-to-an-asp-net-asmx-ajax-web-service

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do something like :

```
var str = JSON.stringify(data)

var city = {};
        city.Directions = str;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'usertrip.aspx/GetDirections',
            data: { city: str },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r.d.Directions);;
                }
        });
```

And in the Webforms code behind:

```
 City city = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<City>(Request.Form["city"]);
```